# How To Make A Windows Application (.EXE), Which Will Run HTML Webpage

Tags: windows, web-applications, exe

I want to create a desktop application for Windows, which will run specified website url in that. for example look this montage- i want a software like fluidapp.com (Mac Support).

montage link-  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65090365/2013/preview.jpg

Comment: The easiest way is to ShellExec.Open() some "http://somesite.com" URL

Comment: You may want to ask this question in **programmers** since you are not specifying a particular platform.  This can be done in an infinite amount of ways.  You're probably trying to build a robot of some sort, but overflow is for very specific question/answer type question.

Comment: @SLaks my question is how to create app like that montage ? so, normally i didnt tried anything.!

Comment: @paulsm4 where to write ? any software ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a windows forms WebBrowser control which should do what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx

Comment: tnx. but where to write those lines ? any software ?